# integration problem in calculating order statistic

Tags: calculus, integration, order-statistics

I am having trouble evaluating the following integral.

Here, $F_{X}(x)$ and $f_{X}(x)$ are the CDF and PDF of an arbitrary continuous random variable $x$ (with domain $(0,1)$). (And so I am trying to calculate the expectation of the order statistic $(L)$ of $F_{X}(x)$.

\begin{equation}
E[f_{x_{(L)}}]=\int_{0}^1 \frac{(2L-1)!}{(L-1)!(L-1)!}(F_{X}(x))^{L}(1-F_{X}(x))^{L}f_{X}(x) x dx
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E[f_{x_{(L)}}]= \frac{(2L-1)!}{(L-1)!^2} \int_{0}^1(F_{X}(x))^{L}(1-F_{X}(x))^{L}f_{X}(x) x dx
\end{equation}

Call $\frac{(2L-1)!}{(L-1)!^2}=J$, and the mean of $F_{X}(x)$ $\mu$. Setting $v=f_{X}(x) x$and $u=(1-F_{X}(x))^{L}F_{X}^{L}$,  I can integrate by parts:
\begin{eqnarray}
J\int uv dx = J[u\int v dx -\int u' (\int v dx) dx]\\
=J[u \mu - \int u' \mu dx] \\
=J[u \mu -\mu \int u' dx] \\
=J[u\mu - \mu u] \\
=0
\end{eqnarray}
This is clearly non-sensical and so I assume I have made a mistake but I am not sure where!

Comment: Well for one, if $v$ is the density of $X$ then it's definite integral is $1$, not $\mu$

Comment: That was a typo -- fixed -- many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replaced the second occurrence of $\int v\,\mathrm dx$ by $\mu$, but $\mu$ is the definite integral from $0$ to $1$, whereas this is the indefinite integral. Your confusion may be related to the invalid notation, in which you denoted both the outer and the inner integration variable by $x$. Things should readily be cleared up if you distinguish the integration variables and write the proper limits on all the integrals.

Comment: I have edited the question to emphasise that the domain of $x$ is $(0,1)$. In this case, is it still invalid to replace the $\int f(x) x dx =\mu$?

Comment: @dothyphendot: That wasn't the problem; it was clear enough from the few integrals on which you did write the limits that the domain was meant to be $(0,1)$. If you reread my answer and follow the suggestion in the last sentence, I think it will become apparent where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks. I know I'm missing something obvious, but I'm banging my head against the wall with this, what is it that I should be noticing?